# I am trying to get the choice type field value in select tag from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

I am trying to get the choice field value in select tag from SharePoint list.

Here, the code is given below:

```
function GetphysicalVertual() {
    var defPG = $.Deferred();
    var inputElement;

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Column Name'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            inputElement = '<option value="0">--Select--</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results; i++) {
                var locationName = data.d.results[i].Choices.results;
                inputElement += '<option value="' + locationName + '">' + locationName + '</option>';
            }
          
            console.log(inputElement);
            $('#ddlphysicalVirtual').append(inputElement);
            $('#ddlphysicalVirtual').each(function () {
                $('option', this).each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '0') {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            });
            defPG.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            defPG.reject(data);
        }
    });
    return defPG.promise();
}
```

Using this code I am not able to get the value.

Comment: Are you getting any error using this API call? Are you trying to get the choices options from choice field OR the value of selected choice option against list item(just confirming)?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error but i am also not getting the choices options from choice field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code which is working fine for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cars" id="ddlphysicalVirtual"></select>
<button type="button" onclick="getChoiceOptions()"> Get Choice Options </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getChoiceOptions() {
        var defPG = $.Deferred();
        var inputElement = "";
        
        var fieldsEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Color'";

        $.ajax({
            url: fieldsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {              
                inputElement += '<option value="0"> --Select-- </option>';
    
                var choicesArray = data.d.results[0].Choices.results
                for (var i = 0; i < choicesArray.length; i++) {
                    var locationName = choicesArray[i];
                    inputElement += '<option value="' + locationName + '">' + locationName + '</option>';
                }
              
                $('#ddlphysicalVirtual').append(inputElement);
    
                $('#ddlphysicalVirtual').each(function () {
                    $('option', this).each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == '0') {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                    });
                });
                
                defPG.resolve(true);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                defPG.reject(false);
            }
        });
        return defPG.promise();
    }
</script>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works for me